# Migrate from Subversion 1.4 to 1.6

Tags: svn, migration

Can somebody please point me in the right direction for migrating a Subversion 1.4 repository to Subversion 1.6 on a different server ? I'd appreciate any help I can get, I'm not having much luck googling this.

Comment: To elaborate, I've already tried doing a dump from 1.4 and loading it into 1.6 (that much is in the subversion redbook and I've even done this before successfully between v1.4 servers).  When I try to load the v1.4 file into a v1.6 server, I get an error about the header format of the dump file.  From what I've read, the repository layout has changed between 1.4 and 1.6

Comment: To further elaborate yet again, these two servers are on different machines with different operating systems.  The 1.4 server is an old gentoo box that's mission critical and can't be upgraded without severe risk of breaking something (which we're working on migrating away from) and the new 1.6 box is running subversion on Windows Server 2003.  I also have no control over the new box, I'm only being temporarily allowed by the network admin to access it and install the new repository for the server he's already setup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I'm not 100% sure that you can move a dump file freely between Linux and Windows. You may have to convert line endings.

Next, you should try to first move the repository in 1.4 format, and then upgrade it in place. One way to do that, on the target machine:

```
svnadmin create --pre-1.5-compatible /path/to/repo
svnadmin load /path/to/repo <dumpfile
svnadmin upgrade /path/to/repo
```

See the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnadmin.html#svn.ref.svnadmin.c) for details of svnadmin.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you kindly for your help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: The dump format is platform independent. So you can safely move the dump file between Linux and Windows.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks, I thought it was, but wasn't sure.

Comment: `--pre-1.5-compatible` is deprecated. Use `--compatible-version` instead.

Answer (score 2):

We did it in a slight different way: we created a new repository and used [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync) to create a mirror of the repository. This one should be used as read-only until the time you want to switch. Then add hooks to the old repository to forbid commits (ideally display and error message telling your users to relocate to the new repository). svnsync a last time and activate the new repository. This was much faster than dumping and more efficient as we could catch up and sync the latest changes to the old repos.

Comment: You can also do incremental dumps and loads.

Comment: This was less a pain for us, for e.g. one of our 1.4 repos had an on-disk space of > 32GB (compressed svn diff) you can then imagine the size of the dump! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make certain that you are treating that dump file as a binary file.  It looks like a text file and you can get away with editing it in a number of ways... but it isn't just text.  So if a newline conversion has occurred during the transfer or something you'd wind up with a mess.